# Localization of UI

Tags: c#

I am working on localization project and when i change the language the UI gets disturbed because some translations are large. For example say there is button with text "Select All". But when this is localized in french it reads as "Sélectionner tout". That is larger than Select All and hence the gui gets affected. Is there any way to localize the gui as well.

Comment: You'll need to say what sort of project this is - WinForms, WPF, web etc.

Comment: its a website and basically the changes are in the aspx pages

Answer (score 1):

since final text for "Select All" can be converted to text of any length, which in this specific case "Select All" is changing to "Sélectionner tout" and you dont want your UI to be disturbed you can give width in % and hope that your final text is having enough space.

I am not sure if there is any way to deal with the width at runtime depending on the length, as in you can count the length and give width in pixels it wont be a good Idea. so have less text and give width in percentage.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a Pseudo culture to handle that.

The pseudo culture will contain the largest translation for a specified string among all cutltures.

For example if you have a Resx file with name strings.resx, and another culture based file maybe in french strings.fr.resx and another in dutch called strings.nl.resx.

Then create another file called string.pseudocult.resx , pseudocult should be replaced with any culture you wouldn't be supporting for example string.az.resx

strings.resx

```
< data name="Select_All" xml:space="preserve">
    < value>Select All</value>
< /data>
```

strings.fr.resx

```
< data name="Select_All" xml:space="preserve">
    < value>Sélectionner tout</value>
< /data>
```

strings.nl.resx

```
< data name="Select_All" xml:space="preserve">
    < value>Alles selecteren</value>
< /data>
```

strings.az.resx

```
< data name="Select_All" xml:space="preserve">
    < value>Sélectionner tout</value>
< /data>
```

The value in the az should be measured by finding the longest string based on GUI using the translations in supported cultures, in this case the longest translation based on GUI was in french culture.
This will essentially provide you the minimum size for each control in your application and also an insight on if you should change the translation.

Otherwise if you want to omit that , you should keep the size of controls containing words with length less than 5 to 300% of original required size and for greater than equal to 5 to about 170% of the original size.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your UI within the Visual Studio Designer and set the property `Localizable` of your `Form` or `UserControl` to `true`. With this step automatically a new `.resx` file will be added to your UI element which contains all values of the properties. This values will be applied in the first step and will get into action if now matching values for the current culture is found.

Next simply switch the `Language` property to the language you want to support which its own set of text and layout. If you now make any changes to your UI you'll set that another `.resx` will be added to your component and any change you make will be written into this file.

So simply create your control as you like, set the `Localizable` property to `true`, switch the `Language` property to the new supported language and adjust the gui as you need.

A more in-depth article about localization can also be found [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3.aspx).